# Why does the discriminator minimize the cross-entropy while the generator maximize it?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, math, generative-adversarial-networks, generative-model

In his original [GAN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661v1.pdf) Goodfellow gives a game theoretic perspective for GANs:

\begin{equation} 
\underset{G}{\min}\, \underset{D}{\max}\, V\left(D,G \right) = 
\mathbb{E}_{x\sim\mathit{p}_{\textrm{data}}\left(x \right)} \left[\textrm{log}\, D \left(x \right) \right]
+ \mathbb{E}_{z\sim\mathit{p}_{\textrm{z}}\left(z \right)} \left[\textrm{log} \left(1 - D \left(G \left(z \right)\right)\right) \right]
\end{equation}

I think I understand this formula, at least it makes sense to me.
What I don't understand is that he writes in his [NIPS tutorial](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.00160.pdf):

> In the minimax game, the discriminator minimizes a cross-entropy, but the generator maximizes the same cross-entropy.

Why does he write that the discriminator **minimizes** the cross-entropy while the generator **maximizes** it? Shouldn't it be the other way around? At least that is how I understand $\underset{G}{\min}\, \underset{D}{\max}\, V\left(D,G \right)$.

I guess this shows that I have a fundamental error in my understanding. Could anyone clarify what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you think that the referenced $V(D,G)$ is the definition of the cross-entropy! Indeed, the cross-entropy is defined based on the negative value of the $V(D,G)$. Hence, if you consider the minus behind the $V(D,G)$ ($-V(D,G)$) the sentence will be meaningful.